# How to rotate a wheel by running on the treadmill

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I'm creating a treadmill cycle. I want to use fewer pieces of equipment as possible. By running on the treadmill how can I rotate the wheel so I can move forward? I don't want to use any electrical pieces of equipment at all. So please suggest me how can I do it. Thank You